# ¿Por que si tengo una pila de tipo double los valores pierden el punto? por ejemplo 4.5 pasa a ser 45? en c#

Tags: c#

Al ejecutar este código primero verifico que el valor guardo en la variable contenido sea correcto al imprimirlo. Si guardo un 4.5 se supone que este se guarda en mi pila. Luego al querer ver el valor almacenado  en la pila es decir el 4.5, con el metodo peek, este me muestra 45 en lugar de 4.5. La verdad que soy bastante principiante agradecería su explicación

```
 MessageBox.Show(Contenido); //imprimo valor decimal
  pilaR.Push(Convert.ToDouble(Contenido));
  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pilaR.Peek()));
 //imprimo valor pero pierde el punto es decir si por ejemplo era un 4.5 esta pasa a ser 45
```

Comment: verifica el locale q seguro espera una , como separador [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que tienes por defecto una cultura por defecto en el compilador que interpreta él punto como separador para miles y no como una coma.
En este caso tienes dos soluciones:
1er Cambiar el input que el separador de los decimales sea una coma.
2nd Cambiar la cultura que usa al convertir el string a double Codigo en question:

```
  stack.Push(Convert.ToDouble(Contenido, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**Importante no se pueden combinar las soluciones anteriores, otras opciones son:**

- Remplazar el punto por la coma o al revés (lo que toque por la cultura) antes de convertir a double el string.
- Clonar CultureInfo que te sea más adecuado y cambiar las propiedades que necesites [Link de ayuda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_Clone)